# kubectl deployment failing

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am working on setting up CI CD pipeline for Spring boot application on GKE. The CI build step worked correctly but the delivery build step is failing due to 'error: no objects passed to apply' error. I could see below logs in the cloud build

```
Starting Step #0 - "Deploy"
Step #0 - "Deploy": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl
Step #0 - "Deploy": Running: gcloud container clusters get-credentials --project="location-finder-kubernetes" --zone="us-central1-b" "location-finder"
Step #0 - "Deploy": Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
Step #0 - "Deploy": kubeconfig entry generated for location-finder.
Step #0 - "Deploy": Running: kubectl apply -f kubernetes.yaml
Step #0 - "Deploy": error: no objects passed to apply
Finished Step #0 - "Deploy"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl" failed: exit status 1
```

where location-finder is the name of the cluster.

To set up this pipeline, I followed all the guidelines mentioned at https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/gitops-cloud-build

The cloudbuild.yaml content for this failing step is

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl'
  id: Deploy
  args:
  - 'apply'
  - '-f'
  - 'kubernetes.yaml'
  env:
  - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=us-central1-b'
  - 'CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=location-finder'
```

Kubectl version:

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11+", GitVersion:"v1.11.9-dispatcher", GitCommit:"e3f5193e8f1091a162af7e17a781e6a3129bcfd0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-03-28T18:13:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11+", GitVersion:"v1.11.8-gke.6", GitCommit:"394ee507d00f15a63cef577a14026096c310698e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-03-30T19:31:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: Hi Swapnil, can you post you `kubernetes.yaml` file?

Comment: As per the steps mentioned in the document, there is a template file called kubectl.yaml.tpl. Using this file, the automated process creates the final kubernetes.yaml file. It was my mistake to forgot to add that template file to source control. @Arslanbekov, your asked for the same file which gave me an hint to figure it out. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 15):

To test, I ran the same `kubectl apply -f kubernetes.yaml`, but passed an empty yaml file and got the same error as you. Is there anyting acutally in your yaml file?

Comment: Yeah this file should not be empty. Refer the document, use it as it is. Just replace the cluster name with your cluster name.

Comment: Ha Ha.  I had started the file with "touch my.yaml".  Brought it up in a VSCode, added a bunch of stuff, BUT never saved it !!  A "duh" moment.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the objects are not defined correctly in the `kubernetes.yaml` file.

Please check the file and verify that you are able to manually deploy it. If it works then the same should work from continuous delivery.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether Visual Studio Code Auto-save is disabled and you have not saved your file. Drove me nuts and realized, the error is exactly what it means.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure saving the file, bacause it happened with me and I took few minutes to notice it:  I started with `touch deploydescriptor.yaml`, opened file in vscode and started mentioning yaml configuration for deployment but never saved it and it started giving `error: no objects passed to apply` when I executed `kubectl apply -f deploydescriptor.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

I am too facing the same issue, refering the Google Docs for CI/CD on GKE.

have you got the solution for the same ?

```
BUILD Starting Step #0 - "Deploy"
Step #0 - "Deploy": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl
Step #0 - "Deploy": Running: gcloud container clusters get-credentials --project="amcartecom" --zone="us-central1-b" "hello-cloudbuild"
Step #0 - "Deploy": Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
Step #0 - "Deploy": kubeconfig entry generated for hello-cloudbuild.
Step #0 - "Deploy": Running: kubectl apply -f kubernetes.yaml
Step #0 - "Deploy": error: no objects passed to apply
Finished Step #0 - "Deploy"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl" failed: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

please check if you have entered namespace in yaml file. This worked for me.

Comment: don't comments on answer section...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when we have any spelling or spacing issues in your deployment/config file. There is no other reason why this is not working.

> To check if your system configurations are fine. you can use below
> file to check if system configurations are fine in your system. If
> both the below steps are working fine then your Kubernetes
> configurations are perfect. Just check the  spelling or spacing
> issues. and your file is saved properly with .yaml extention

**Step 1:** Try to check if your Kubernetes is running properly or not using `kubectl version` command. You must see something like this, it means your Kubernetes is running properly:

[image]

**Step 2:** Use this basic file to create the Pod.  It must create a Pod.

`Note: In image:, put your image path`

app-depl.yaml file code:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: app-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: users
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: users
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: posts
          image: image sha256:ced8014b9cddb9ca4c81ced8ced801ced80175ab445cced801
```

[image]