# CI CD Pipeline on GKE - Deployment failing ("Deploy": error: no objects passed to apply)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-build

I am working on setting up CI CD pipeline for Spring boot application on GKE. The CI build step worked correctly but the delivery build step is failing due to 'error: no objects passed to apply' error. I could see below logs in the cloud build

```
    starting build "0b2761ac-15e0-4dc7-bd37-595ae2ce6916"

FETCHSOURCE
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
From https://source.developers.google.com/p/amcartecom/r/eureka-cloudbuild-env
 * branch            ebd6994bed5bc58e37567156451c2fb957ae4fbd -> FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at ebd6994 Deploying image gcr.io/amcartecom/eureka-cloudbuild:v1 Built from commit a61084943388477a490cfabf5430a93c699f0574 of repository eureka-cloudbuild-app Author: nsingla8585 <nsingla85@gmail.com>
BUILD
Starting Step #0 - "Deploy"
Step #0 - "Deploy": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl
Step #0 - "Deploy": Running: gcloud container clusters get-credentials --project="amcartecom" --zone="us-central1-b" "hello-cloudbuild"
Step #0 - "Deploy": Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
Step #0 - "Deploy": kubeconfig entry generated for hello-cloudbuild.
Step #0 - "Deploy": Running: kubectl apply -f kubernetes.yaml
Step #0 - "Deploy": error: no objects passed to apply
Finished Step #0 - "Deploy"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl" failed: exit status 1
```

To set up this pipeline, I followed all the guidelines mentioned at https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/gitops-cloud-build

Comment: From the error message you get, it looks like there is something wrong with your kubernetes.yaml file. Can you update the question with what's included in that file?

Comment: To complete siamsot comment, I would say that looking at your error the file kubernetes.yaml does not exist in your current path... It would also help to have your repository arborescence to files

Comment: I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55791485/kubectl-deployment-failing?answertab=votes#tab-top) similar other discussion thread, where the issue has been resolved by adding a template file(kubectl.yaml.tpl) to source control. I hope this helps

Comment: I found that issue exist at Step 4 while generating manifest,                     Starting Step #4 - "Generate manifest"
Step #4 - "Generate manifest": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Step #4 - "Generate manifest": sed: can't read kubernetes.yaml.tpl: No such file or directory
Finished Step #4 - "Generate manifest"

Comment: It seems like as per [this github.com](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-gitops-tutorial-cloudbuild/issues/3), the ".tpl" file should be in your "app" repository, not in the "env" repository. Can you double check?

Comment: Yes, that exist in the "app" repository, but not sure how it throws the error "No such File or directory". Something wrong at step 4 in cloudbuild.yaml . Please have a look on below code:                                                                                 { `code  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  id: Generate manifest
  entrypoint: /bin/sh
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
     sed "s/GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT/${PROJECT_ID}/g" kubernetes.yaml.tpl | \
     sed "s/COMMIT_SHA/v1/g" > zuul-cloudbuild-env/kubernetes.yaml `

Comment: Most likely a configuration issue. Try to [clean-up](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/gitops-cloud-build#clean-up) the resources and then re-build it.